# Laravel - create link with parameters from object

Tags: laravel, routes

i have problem with creating links in blade.

When i have route like this:

```
Route::get('user/profile/{id}','UserController@showProfile')->name('profile');
```

and i want to create link in blade template like:

```
{{ route('routeName', ['id' => 1]) }}
```

but i will want to create the link directly from user object, will be possible to create link with parameters from object instance? like:

```
{{ route('routeName', $userobject) }}
```

Of course, `$userobject` has a property called `id`: `($userobject->id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please take care when using this solution, because this will directly affect on both toArray() and toJson() functions**

You can set **$visible** property inside your user model:

```
class User extents Eloquent {
   ....
   private $visible = ['id'];
   ....
}
```

so when you call the route with the model as parameter, Laravel will call the **toJson()** function inside eloquent object and the result will be only the id of user object:

```
{{ route('routeName', $userobject) }}
```

You may read its [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json) for further information.